# Minimum Numbers to find the given average.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

Average score of the player (sum of scores in all the games / no. of games) is given. How Can we find  the minimum number of games the player should have played to achieve that average.
scores are non negative numbers.
eg. Average score is :- 30.25
  minimum number of games :- 4

Comment: you might consider writing the average as a fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Write the average score $x$ as a reduced fraction $x=\frac{p}q$. This means that $p$ and $q$ are integers, that $q$ is positive and that $q$ is minimal (or, equivalently, that $p$ and $q$ have no nontrivial common factor). Then the player can have played any multiple of $q$ games hence the minimum number of games the player should have played is $q$.

When $x=-30.25$, note that $-30.25=-\frac{121}{4}$ and $-121$ and $4$ have no common factors except $+1$ and $-1$, hence the minimum number of games is indeed $4$.

Comment: It is possible that what OP doesn't know is how to write a given $x$ as a fraction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True.